# cannot use make to create pdf

Tags: pdf, make, latex, dvi

I am trying to compile the C ref posted by Stallman https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/c-intro-and-ref.git
and I am getting this error when I try to run `make c.pdf`:

```
c-intro-and-ref$ make c.pdf 
tex c.texi
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
(./c.texi (./texinfo.tex Loading texinfo [version 2018-01-09.11]: pdf, fonts,
markup, glyphs, page headings, tables, conditionals, indexing, sectioning,
toc, environments, defuns, macros, cross references, insertions,
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/epsf/epsf.tex
This is `epsf.tex' v2.7.4 <14 February 2011>
) localization, formatting, and turning on texinfo input format.)
Writing index file c.fn

Overfull \hbox (30.46255pt too wide) detected at line 45
 @titlerm GNU C Language Intro and Reference Manual |
[1] (./c.tmp))
Runaway argument?
^^M^^MYou can call @code{main} from C code, as you can call any other@ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of @next.
<inserted text> 
                @par 
<*> c.texi
          
?
```

How can I resolve this?

EDIT: I am downloading stallman's C refrence he posted this week.
I followed this guide to get it https://www.i-programmer.info/news/184-cc/15705-richard-stallman-announces-c-reference.html and it works but its only for getting a html format of it. the c ref is called c.tex which i wanted to use the provided MAKEFILE inside the git repo and create a c.pdf from it.
when I get this error I dont know what to do and it will only result in the pdf file getting its first page and not the rest.
I edited the image to instead show the code block

EDIT2: hello everyone there seems to be problems with the .texi file and not the makefile that I thought didnt work. someone has already made the pdf here https://www.cyberciti.biz/files/GNU-C-Language-Manual/GNU%20C%20Language%20Manual.pdf he/she didnt say how they fixed the problem exactly though.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer on the LaTeX Stack Exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111956)? It should give you what you need 

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. What did you download? How? What exactly is the file `c.pdf`? Does it exist? Is it a pdf file? What Makefile are you using? Also, please don't post images of text, just copy/paste the text directly into your question so it can be searchble and we can also copy it for our search.

Comment: @matigo the overfull hbox message is just a warning and shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I edited it according to what you told me and gave more info and linked the resource I used to try to make the pdf @terdon

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that helps! However, it looks like something is missing on your system. I checked out the git repo and then ran `make c.pdf` and it worked as expected. However, on my system, it was compiled by `pdfTeX`, while on yours, I see the output mentions `This is TeX, Version 3.141592653` instead. The `pdftex` executable is installed by the `texlive-binaries` on Ubuntu, have you installed that package?

Comment: @terdon I do https://jpst.it/2X-a8
```
pdflatex c.texi 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./c.texi
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21> (./texinfo.tex
Loading texinfo [version 2018-01-09.11]: pdf, fonts,
! Undefined control sequence.
\resetmathfonts ...ont 2=\syfont \textfont \itfam 
                                                  =\itfont \textfont \slfam ...
l.2645 \definetextfontsizexi
                        
? 
```

Comment: use this link if its hard to read https://jpst.it/2X-a8

Comment: Please add all new info to your question. And also tell us exactly what commands you ran, what packages you installed etc (don't just tell us you followed the guide, we need to know exactly what you did). In any case, the command is `make c.pdf`, don't call `pdflatex` directly, run `make c.pdf`.

Comment: I only installed texlive-latex-recommended and extra and texlive-fonts-recommended and extra and that error was from make c.pdf also I made a new edit saying I recently heard from someone who made the pdf that the problem is from the .texi file and not makefile itself. @terdon 
if someone knows how to fix the .texi file, please post it here as I do not know and only recently learned about tex and texi format.

Comment: Please add the exact commands you ran to your question. The texi file is fine and `make c.pdf` works fine on my system which is why I think you must be missing some TeX packages.

Comment: this is the result of apt list --installed | grep tex https://pastebin.com/zBVhrX2Z and the only command I run is make c.pdf